# Intermittent SSLPeerUnverifiedException thrown from RestAssured within Cucumber test

Tags: macos, ssl, gradle, cucumber, rest-assured

We have a couple of Cucumber test scenarios, which use RestAssured framework for hitting HTTPS endpoints. When we run the entire suite of scenarios, we face intermittent "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated" exceptions thrown from the the following line of code

> Response response = given().log().all().headers(headers).contentType(ContentType.JSON)                .with().body(somebody).put(path, testId);

This is an intermittent issue, observed both in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 and from Terminal, on Mac OSX. We are using Jayway RestAssured v2.3.2 on a gradle build.

The server we are hitting has a self-signed certificate, and we tried the following:

1) Adding the certificate to the Mac Keychain manually - still intermittent

2) Using useRelaxedHTTPSValidation() as mentioned [here](http://www.hascode.com/2011/10/testing-restful-web-services-made-easy-using-the-rest-assured-framework/) - still intermittent

3) Using the following in the code

> RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(sslConfig().allowAllHostnames());

from the same blog post - all tests fail with the above exception consistently

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding the certificate to the truststore should help. Have you configured your JVM to use the Mac KeychainStore as a truststore? Unless this has changed recently, this isn't the default: even on OSX the JRE comes with its own cacerts store.

Comment: @Bruno Based off your suggestion, I added `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Library/Java/Home/lib/security/cacerts` in my idea.vmoptions file, and to the command line. However, I still see the same intermittent behaviour.